Why training model with (Batch, 90, 7) Is slower than (Batch, 90, 8)?
Using tensorflow
I am using the following model:
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(90, 7)))
model.add(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(70, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(70, return_sequences=False)) 
model.add(Dense(20, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(22, activation='softmax'))

When the first layer is:
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(90, 7)))
the training time (for each epoch) is  slower then when the first layer is:
model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(90, 8)))
It seems that when the input is larger the GPU handle it faster.

why is it ?
Is it better to use model.add(Masking(mask_value=0.0, input_shape=(90, 8))) and set the last dim of the input with zeros ?


If you keep adding new dimention, will the training go continously faster? It seems not ideal to measure this things, could you please provide reproducible code?
